# Saving Django models data to Database for derived class

Tags: django, django-models, revitpythonshell

I have below models

```
class Student(models.Model):
    fname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dob=models.DateField()


class StudentDetail(Student):
    Subject=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    marks=models.IntegerField()
```

I am able to create Student objects. I try to add StudentDetail as below

```
student=Student()
student.fname='fname text'
student.lname='lname text'
student.mname='mname text'
student.dob='2020-01-01'
student.save()

detail1=StudentDetail()
detail1.subject='subject text'
detail1.marks=78
detail1.save()
```

the last statement gives error. How to save StudentDetail in database.

Comment: You are adding wrong fields in StudentDetail model. StudentDetail model don't have "address" and "student" field.

Comment: Thanks, I by mistake copied code but doesn't change the code. it worked.